# Shortcut to Toggle F1-F12 function keys on Lenovo Yoga / Lenovo Vantage

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, lenovo-vantage

On my Lenovo Yoga (C940 Model) I can toggle how the top row of the keboard works through the Lenovo Vantage Software, as pictured:

[image]

But to achieve this, every time I have to open the software and then navigate to the menu. Since I need to switch this often, I'd like to have some sort of shortcut. A desktop link, taskbar button ... anything which either allows me to automate the switch, or takes me directly to that page of the Vantage software.
I'm grateful for any tip on how to achieve this.
(<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> is not anymore in the BIOS. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is easy: it's in the "Quick Settings" which pop up when clicking on the Lenovo battey icon (see the "arrow" in the image below), there's a dedicated button for swithching the "Keyboard top-row function" (red square in the image below).

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I am running Windows 10 Home Version 2004 on a Lenovo YOGA 910-131KB Signature Edition.  I searched everywhere for a solution before finding your answer.